# Eigenvector and eigevalues of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for: ${\rm proj}_v:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$

I have no idea how to answer this! Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Choose a basis for $V$ and extend it to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is the matrix of $\text{proj}_V$ with respect to this basis?

Comment: The problem does not give a matrix!

Comment: The problem need not give a matrix - the matrix with respect to the basis I described is easy to find. Try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ an eigenvector of $p$ associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ then
$$p(x)=\lambda x\in\operatorname{im}(p)\implies p(x)=p^2(x)=\lambda p(x)$$
hence if $p(x)\ne0\iff x\not\in \ker p$ then $\lambda=1$ and if $x\in\ker p$ then $p(x)=0=\lambda x\implies \lambda=0$. We conclude that

- $0$ is an eigenvalue and the eigenspace is $\ker p$;
- $1$ is an eigenvalue and the eigenspace is $\operatorname{im}(p)$.

Comment: Could you be so kinda as to explain with words what you have written! Thanks!

Comment: What you didn't understand?

Comment: $p(x)$ is the transformation. Why is $p(x)=p^2(x)...$

Comment: $p$ isn't *any* transformation; it's a *projection* so we have $p^2=p$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link! I will read it now :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: why is it that $\lambda=1$ and not any arbitrary value if $x ∉ ker$ $p$